# jquery lightbox won't work in css3 based website

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery

I am attempting to use a CSS-based website template to re-build my portfolio site. 
Here is the URL: http://www.annasportfolio.com/iindex.html

I have been unsuccessful at adding an image gallery to the second section (design). Something isn't lining up, but I don't know what. Is it a conflict of jquery?

My Head code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqGalScroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#demoOne").jqGalScroll();}); </script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script> <!--[if lte IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simple.css" /><![endif]-->
```

The Area Where the image gallery should lie:

```
<section class="st-panel st-color" id="st-panel-2">
<div class="st-deco" data-icon="1"></div>
<h2>Happiness</h2>
<p>Filler Text</p><!-- Design LightBox/ -->
<ul id="one">
<li><img alt="" src="bittennyc.png" border="0" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2194/2037390693_8acc544048.jpg" border="0" />
</li> 
</ul></section>
```

Comment: Check the errors in your console. None of your JS files are found so of course it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1: 
    `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#demoOne").jqGalScroll();}); </script>`

Put this in the body. And be sure the jquery.js is loaded correctly in the body (look for the second tip).

2: In your site, apparently there is problem with your JS files, check the references and access permissions.